# Force using same citation style

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

(EDITED)

I cite two following articles using \cite{..} (apa6 class)

In bibfile:

```
@InProceedings{a,
    title={a},
    author={Alast, Afirst and Blast, Bfirst and Clast, Cfirst},
    year={2010}
}

@InProceedings{b,
    title = {b},
    author={Alast, Afirst and Blast, Bfirst and Clast, Cfirst},
    year={2010}
}
```

The result when I cite:

```
\cite{a} generates Alast et al (2010a).
\cite{b} generates Alast, Blast, and Clast (2010b)
```

In the document:

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
...
\bibliography{bibfile}
```

So, two exactly same authors list but inconsistent citation style happens.

It is puzzle for me and I don't know how to correct it.
Please help me!

Comment: Please provide a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior. I'm afraid I am unable to reproduce the problem based on just the information you've provided so far. Please help eliminate any pointless guesswork.

Comment: As long as we're guessing, I'm guessing you may want to change your author format to "Afirst Alast and Bfirst Blast and Cfirst Clast and Dfirst Dlast and Efirst Elast and Ffirst Flast".

Comment: @MikeRenfro Just for curiosoty: why? I am also using this system with lastname, firstname because I find it easier to read when working with the bib-file. Is there any reason why one should not do so? I never ran into any problems with that (in fact it even makes things easier with von parts, authors having unhyphenated double family names and so on).

Comment: Apparently it doesn't matter in this case, it's just a habit I've built up. Regardless, I can't reproduce your problem yet.

Answer (score 1):

(Placeholder answer to find proper MWE:)

With or without your additional packages, I can't reproduce your symptoms. The `apacite` package is already loaded when you use the `apacite` option in your document class. But the following shows the same author style on both citations:

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{a,
    title={a},
    author={Alast, Afirst and Blast, Bfirst and Clast, Cfirst},
    year={2010}
}

@InProceedings{b,
    title = {b},
    author={Alast, Afirst and Blast, Bfirst and Clast, Cfirst},
    year={2010}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \cite{a}
\item \cite{b}
\end{itemize}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Please verify this document works correctly for you, and then you can start narrowing down the source of your problem.